# rspec expect to change flash fails in nested block

Tags: error-handling, rspec, flash-message

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I have a controller that needs to call 2 methods in my model. Both of these model methods can throw errors on failure so I've set up the controller to only call the second if the first succeeds. For example:

```
member_action :controller_method, :method => :post do
  begin
    model.method_1!
  rescue => e
    flash[:error] = "Method1 failed with error #{e}"
  else
    begin
      model.method_2!
    rescue => e
      flash[:error] "Method1 was successful but Method2 failed with error #{e}"
    else
      flash[:success] = "Method1 and Method 2 were successful."
    end
  end
end
```

And my test looks like this:

```
it "flashes success" do
  expect { post "method1_and_method2" }.to change { flash[:success] }
end
```

I've tried putting the flash[:success] message in the first block and that works fine. It's only when it's nested in the second block that it fails. I've tested it myself and the flash[:success] is showing up as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I needed to mock out the controller instance variable and specify that it received and returned true for both methods. Here's what the passing test looks like:

```
before do
  Model.should_receive(:find_by_id).and_return(model)
end

it "flashes success" do
  model.should_receive(:method_1!).and_return(true)
  model.should_receive(:method_2!).and_return(true)
  expect { post "method1_and_method2" }.to change { flash[:success] }
end
```